# Can kernel module use kernel data structures?

Tags: data-structures, kernel, kernel-module

When writing a kernel module, can programmer make use of data structures, like task_group, task_struct, already defined in kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, after including corresponding header, kernel module can use anything that is *defined* in that header: data structures, macros, static inline functions...

As for functions, *declared* in the header file and *implemented* in kernel's source file, only those which are exported using EXPORT_SYMBOL/EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL can be used in modules.

Comment: What if I want to use headers that are not located under `include/` directory of the kernel tree? Specifically, I need definition of `struct cfs_rq`, which is defined in `kernel/sched/sched.h`. Copying the header seems impractical since structures defined amid `struct cfs_rq`

Comment: Things defined in `kernel/sched/sched.h` are **not intended** to be used outside of the schedule implementation. If you want to modify the scheduler, then modify sources under `kernel/sched`. Otherwise completely avoid using fields of `struct cfs_rq`.